# How to convert a string to to Title Case in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want a function that capitalizes the first letter of each word in a string in pure Javascript.

For example:

```
console.log(titleCase("I'm a little teapot"));
//I'm A Little Teapot
```

The function can't use `.split` or `.map`.

Here is what I tried:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    str.toLowerCase();
    var string="";
    for(var i=0 ;i<str.length;i++){
        if(i===0){
            str[0].toUpperCase();
            string+=str[0];
        } else if(str[i]===" "){
            str[i+1].toUpperCase();
            string+=str[i]+str[i+1];
        }
        string+=str[i]; 
    }
    return  string;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"without any type of method"*?

Comment: without split()  and map() .....

Comment: Why is `split` and `map` not allowed but ( `toUpperCase`, `toLowerCase`, and `length`) are allowed? Those are all "methods"...

Comment: I mean  you can use toUpperCase, toLowerCase, and length is there is any way to solve this without  split and map thnx

Comment: Sure, there is a way,  but there is also a way to solve this without any methods at all.  So why exclude some but not others?

Comment: I think to not complicated thing very much can show me how to do it without any method

Comment: is my code make sense

Comment: I added an update without using any methods at all.

Comment: @AbdelilahZaidane see my updated code for an example with no `map()` or `split()` funcs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite verbose, but, alas, **`titleCase`** without any "methods":

```
var charDict = {'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'C', ...};

function titleCase(str){
    var i = 0;
    var result = '';

    while (str[i]) {
        var char = str[i];
        if (((i === 0) || (str[i-1] === ' ')) && (char in charDict)) {
          result += charDict[char];
        }
        else {
          result += char;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that you will have to add every character to **`charDict`** for this to actually work.

I'd strongly discourage using this in production code.  Instead I would use [Aaron's first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59700316/10746224).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) the string into an array, [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) each item in the array into your desired format, and then [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) the array back into a string again.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  return str.split(" ").map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)).join(" ");
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little teapot"));
```

But if you don't want to use split or map, you can do this:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  var newStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    newStr += (i == 0 || str[i - 1] == " ") ? str[i].toUpperCase() : str[i];
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little teapot"));
```

Comment: No problem. You need a simple version without split/map?

Comment: Ok, I took out all methods except toUpperCase(). Is toUpperCase() fine?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"

let res = str.split(" ").map(word => {
    let arr = word.split("")
    return arr.map((let, idx)  => idx === 0 ? let.toUpperCase() : let).join("")  
}).join(" ")

console.log(res)
```

### Update

Without map() or split():

```js
let str = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"

let firstLet = false

for(let i=0; i<str.length; i++){

    if(i==0 || firstLet && str[i] !== " "){
        str = str.substr(0, i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.substr(i + 1);
        firstLet = false
    }
    if(str[i] === " "){
        firstLet = true
    }
}

console.log(str)
```

Comment: great thanx bro

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight improvement to the above code in performance with a lesser number of operations and time complexity.

```
const res = str.split(" ").map(word => 
    `${word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+word.substr(1)}`
).join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is by using ASCII:

```
public String upperCase(String words) {
 String res = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
  int ascii = (int) words.charAt(i);
  if (ascii > 96 && ascii < 123) {
   res += (char)(ascii - 32);
  } else {
   res += (char) ascii;
  }
 }
 return res;
}
```